# Unable to debug JS file in developer tools

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webpack, knockout.js

I have an ASP.NET MVC application developed using knockout js and webpack.

When I run the application, then open developer tools and search for any js file, it is not showing.

When I make changes in HTML, that change is shown in the UI.

When I make changes in typescript, that change is NOT shown and throws an error.

I tried setting breakpoints and none are hit. I figured that my local ts/js files are not running and I am unable to figure where web pack is running these files.

Any pointers to how I can run my local js files?

Comment: Change the webpack mode to `development`. Add a `debugger;` in the code you want to debug and then open the dev tools and refresh

Comment: @adiga Where can I change it? I mean which file?

Comment: Do  you have a webpack.config.js or anything with a similar name?

Comment: write a console.log on your code and when open the console, click on the file name at the end of the console line to look into the source code.